# Execution of external optimizer on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am thinking of using the SciPy Optimizer [`tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(...)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/ScipyOptimizerInterface) in my program. A sample use case would be

```
vector = tf.Variable([7., 7.], 'vector')

# Make vector norm as small as possible.
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(vector))

optimizer = ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, options={'maxiter': 100})

with tf.Session() as session:
    optimizer.minimize(session)

# The value of vector should now be [0., 0.].
```

Since `ScipyOptimizerInterface` is a child of `ExternalOptimizerInterface`, I was wondering where the processing of the data is done. Is it on the GPU or the CPU? Since you have to implement the function within the TensorFlow graph I assume at least the function calls and gradients are done on the GPU if available, but what about the calculations needed to do the update? How should I use these kinds of optimizers to be very efficient? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [code on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f43d458a318d4d97298710654f1692f6e8364f82/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/external_optimizer.py#L402), no, this is just a wrapper that does call `scipy` eventually, hence the update is on CPU and cannot be changed.

However, you can find a [native implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/master/tensorflow_probability/python/optimizer/bfgs.py) in [tensorflow/probability](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability), from their example:

```
minimum = np.array([1.0, 1.0])  # The center of the quadratic bowl.
scales = np.array([2.0, 3.0])  # The scales along the two axes.

# The objective function and the gradient.
def quadratic(x):
    value = tf.reduce_sum(scales * (x - minimum) ** 2)
    return value, tf.gradients(value, x)[0]

start = tf.constant([0.6, 0.8])  # Starting point for the search.
optim_results = tfp.optimizer.bfgs_minimize(
      quadratic, initial_position=start, tolerance=1e-8)

with tf.Session() as session:
    results = session.run(optim_results)
    # Check that the search converged
    assert(results.converged)
    # Check that the argmin is close to the actual value.
    np.testing.assert_allclose(results.position, minimum)
    # Print out the total number of function evaluations it took. Should be 6.
    print ("Function evaluations: %d" % results.num_objective_evaluations)
```

Comment: Well, the BFGS optimizer is just one of the many optimizers implemented in the scipy optimizer. But still, this was the answer I was looking for. Thanks!